# Recursive decimal to binary conversion print error

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def decimaltobinary(value):
    if value > 1:
        decimaltobinary(value // 2)
        print(value % 2)
```

whenever I try to run this code everything works fine but I don't get the first binary value.
Example when the program prints 9 the output is 001 instead of the binary value for 9 which is 1001.

Comment: Did you try converting 1 to binary, and use a debugger to find out why it doesn't print anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `else` condition:

```
def decimaltobinary(value):
    if value > 1:
        decimaltobinary(value // 2)
        print(value % 2)
    else:
        print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what happens when value = 0 or value = 1, that should show your problem. Apart from that there's an easy fix:

```
def decimaltobinary(value):
    if value > 1:
        decimaltobinary(value // 2)
    print(value % 2)
```